# Powershell $PROFILE points to an invalid location in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-7.0

I have my PowerShell profile all set up with custom modules and stuff. But the $PROFILE points to an invalid location.

```
PS C:\Users\akris> $profile
C:\Users\akris\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
PS C:\Users\akris>
```

My profile is at `C:\Users\akris\Documents\PowerShell`, you can see that somehow an extra `\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` is appended to the original $profile string.

I checked my Registry entry, but it is fine. Value of **Personal**: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

How do I change the value of $PROFILE to point to `C:\Users\akris\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Thanks in advance. Please forgive me if the question seems ambiguous.

EDIT:
Thanks to @CherryDT, the value of **Personal** is incorrect. It must be `%USERPRODILE%\Documents`

Comment: It's not fine. `Personal` should be `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`.

Comment: @CherryDT Oh! I will try and update on this, thank you :)